# what is replacement for textTheme in flutter. I'm getting following error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter getting this error. can anyone please help with this?  trying to and text styles.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/location_detail/location_detail.dart';
import 'style.dart';


class App extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home:LocationDetail(),
     theme:ThemeData(
       appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
         textTheme: TextTheme(title: AppBarTextStyle)
       )
     )
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you used material TextTheme title doesn't exist you need to call `caption` or something

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toolBarTextStyle` and `titleTextStyle` instead of `textTheme`.
For more details please refer below link
[textTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/textTheme.html#:%7E:text=textTheme%20property%20Null%20safety&text=This%20property%20is%20deprecated%2C%20please,property%20is%20null%2C%20then%20AppBarTheme.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `titleTextStyle` like this:

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
     titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)
)

appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      ' ',
      style: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle,
    ),
```